# Politically correct substitutes for (fe)male and (wo)man

Tags: antonyms, hypernyms, grammatical-gender, political-correctness

In the English language, the pairs *man/woman* and *male/female* both *look* as if one gender or sex was considered a special case for it is denoted by putting an arbitrary prefix (*wo-*, *fe-*) before the default case (*man*, *male*).

It [has been asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76901/78498) whether this is actually the case etymologically, and the answer was “partially” (*woman* < *wif+man*). However, since **werman* or **wereman* is antiquated, **what possible substitutes are there for the pair *man/woman*** or either part thereof when you want to distinguish by gender (so cannot use *person*, *people* or *human*) without the implied sexism of marked and unmarked words?

The ones I can think of as a non-native speaker are either too formal, like *gent/lady*, or too informal, e.g. *guy/gal* and *lad/lass*, or otherwise inadequate for the general case, e.g. *boy/girl*. Using a French loan word *man/fem(me)* or a contraction/neologism *man/*wom* is problematic because *man* is also still used in a generic sense (*mankind* etc.), which cannot be replaced by *human* easily.

Likewise, **which alternatives are there for *male/female*** used as either nouns or adjectives?

I would assume *masculine/feminine* was a possible and preferable alternative, though available as adjectives only. The contraction or neologism *male/*fele* shows nice symmetry, especially with *man/*fem* as introduced above, but it’s artificial, and so is **mascule/*femine*.

Comment: I'd add that in other languages this "derivation" of woman from man is not that 'evident' : *hombre y  mujer, homme et femme, uomo e donna, Mann und Frau.*

Comment: The actual history is certainly sexist, whatever about certain perceived histories. Taking a word that covers all humans, whether *weres*, *wyfs* or *childern* and applying it only to the adult males values the adult males more in considering them the default case.

Comment: Do you take issue with the portions of 'man' and 'male' specifically? Or are you just wanting variety?

Comment: @t0rn Although I basically agree with Jon Hanna for _man_, I’m particularly puzzled by _wo-man_ and _fe-male_. Look at Josh61’s examples from other languages, in all pairs members have about the same complexity and length, whereas in English one gender has labels with an extra syllable compared to the other.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up your assumption in the first paragraph? It seems to me (as a feminist) that you are perhaps constructing a strawman version of feminist ideas.

Comment: @mikeagg I’m more experienced with German linguistic feminism where pronouns like _man_ ‘one/you’, _jemand_ ‘someone’ and _niemand_ ‘no-one’ have been criticized because they were to reminiscent of _Mann_ ‘man’. And I have seen _womanager_ and _herstory_ in English, albeit with a bit of a smirk. That is why I wrote “I assume”. If English linguistic feminists never criticize _woman_ and _female_, that leaves me pretty surprised accordingly. If they do, however, there should be recommendations for alternatives coming with that. This is what I’m asking about and looking for.

Comment: **Womyn** and **wimmin** get used: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Wimmen

Comment: @WayfaringStranger In addition, I also found _wofem_ in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wofem). It also shows that _*wom_ already has some (diametral) definitions, _women over rates, white old men, waste of money_, and that _*fem_ is an alternate spelling of _femme_, i.e. the feminine part of a lesbian relationship.

Comment: @Crissov I hadn't heard of *wofem*. You could have great fun with that, adding an L for some cosplay! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosplay

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for a practical answer, not a theoretical one: politically correct terms that are acceptable in practice. So I looked for competing terms that are actually being adopted in the wild.

According to the Google Books Ngram Viewer, the proposed replacement for *woman* that shows [evidence of adoption](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=womyn%2Cwomban%2Cwomon%2Cwomin&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwomyn%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwomyn%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWomyn%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWOMYN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomban%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwomon%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwomon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWomon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwomin%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwomin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWomin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWOMIN%3B%2Cc0) in literature is ***womyn***. It is now used about [one time in five thousand](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=womyn%20%2F%20woman&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28womyn%20/%20woman%29%3B%2Cc0) in place of *woman*.

The proposed replacement for the plural form *women* that shows [evidence of adoption](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wimmin%2Cwimyn&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwimmin%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwimmin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWimmin%3B%2Cc0) is ***wimmin***. It is now used about [one time in ten thousand](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wimmin%20%2F%20women&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28wimmin%20/%20women%29%3B%2Cc0) in place of *women*.

These frequencies are very small, but have been trending upward since around 1975. They are evidence that these are the primary competing terms, but not evidence of widespread acceptance in literature.

Unlike *womyn*/*wimmen*, there is not yet a competing term for *female*. The term ****fele*** has been proposed satirically, but no effort has been made to promote its actual use and there is no evidence in literature that it is gaining acceptance.

Comment: I’m awarding the bounty to this answer, although I was hoping for something more – *um* – ambitious, but if this the best accepted or only notable proposal, so be it. Note that the terms had been mentioned before in a comment by @WayfaringStranger.

Comment: A potential issue with wimmin is that it is similar to attempts to transcribe a certain rural accent, which is often associated with a stereotypically discriminatory worldview - the opposite of the intended message.

Answer (score 9):

"Female" comes via French from Latin femella, the diminutive of femina "woman". It does not come from "male" and there is no reason for any feminist to want to ban it.

"Woman" does come from "man", but for some reason no one seems to object to it.

Comment: I just edited the question to highlight that actual history is not important really.

Comment: Well said! I'm for equality not unnecessary witch hunts of particular, traditional words. (Not that I'm saying that's what you intended Crissov - it may well not have been.)

Comment: You are right, @t0rn, I don’t necessarily want to use alternatives, but wonder why this seems to be criticized so little by feminists. Maybe that’s the answer, though: there simply are no good alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't criticized because "woman" derives from words meaning "woman (wif) human being (man)" and not from words meaning wife-man in the modern sense.  See www.etymonline.com

Answer (score 0):

I hereby incorporate by reference my answer to a similar question on [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/identifying-studies-on-how-english-language-reflects-sexism/1053#1053)

To add another thought, as long as there are people who call a woman a "woman", who have sexist attitudes in their hearts, that term (or any other term) will be sexist. So until there is no sexism, the politically correct people will need to be outfoxing the sexists by coining new terms. This should be related to the general process whereby enemy tribes (of the same ancestors) gradually develop different languages.

Comment: What you’re describing has been called the _euphemism treadmill_ by Steven Pinker. It’s a very active pattern with other -isms (e.g. _negro, colored, black, African …_) and is encountered with sexism as well (e.g. _Miss, Ms. …_). However, your major point over at Linguistics is that sexism is “culturally relative” and I agree, but whenever one sex or gender is taken to be the standard or default and the other(s) a deviation or specialization, that’ll be considered sexist some day. Generic _he_ or _man_ is therefore seen as problematic. I wonder why the words _wo|man_ and _fe|male_ aren’t yet.

Comment: @Crissov The "euphemism treadmill" is a great concept and I'm glad to see it brought up. There are about ten questions now on the site that refer to it. But I think it's not applicable to "woman" and "female". "Woman" and "female" are not generally regarded as derogatory. Respelling them is not an attempt at euphemism. It's an attempt at "consciousness raising". I discussed consciousness raising in [another answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/104565/14073).

Comment: @MετάEd You’re right about current English, but I meant that the euphemism treadmill might apply to possible substitutes for _woman_ and _female_ if they were adopted not by heart but as a fig leaf. In German, for instance, _Frau_ replaced _Weib_ as least marked term for ‘woman’ (and ‘wife’), but ‘female’ is still _weiblich_.

Answer (score -2):

The only gender neutral word that comes to my mind is "lady". It however isn't sufficient in all contexts.
Language such as English adopted words from many different languages. If we are unable to find the word in English then we should take them from other languages. I would suggest a Hindi alternative to that. In hindi female is referred as 'स्त्री'(strī ) or नारी (nārī). Synonyms of both in english are "Woman" and "Female"